# Xam plugin : CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show doesn't work on Samsung S8 (after latest updates)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Local Notifications

```
using Plugin.LocalNotifications;

[...]

CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show();
```

stopped working after latest update(s) to the android phone : Samsung Galaxy S8  (though it works fine on emulators/tablets etc.).

Any Ideas why?

Comment: Please post your code to help us ;)

Comment: Thanks : this is the code I call on a button click : 
  CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("GC alert(s)!", "Test Message");

Comment: 1) Did factory reset on Samsung Galaxy S8 
2) executed this line of code :  
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("alert(s)!", "Testing..if Local Notification is supported");

3) GOT THIS ERROR : 'Failed to post notification on channel "null"'. 
Any ideas? am I missing anything?